# How to accept or check multiple links in router.pathname.startsWith in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I check multiple URL links with **router.pathname.startsWith** ?

currently im using

```
router.pathname.startsWith("/blogs/", "/webinars/")
```

but its only checking the first link "/blogs/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method is for postion so you have to use it this way :

```
if (router.pathname.startsWith("/blogs/") || router.pathname.startsWith("/webinars/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if `/blogs/` **or** `/webinars` is included in pathname, you can do something like this

```js
if (router.pathname.includes("/blogs/") || router.pathname.includes("/webinars/")) { // your code... }
```

But if you want to check if `/blogs/` **and** `/webinars/` are included in pathname, you can do something like this

```js
if (router.pathname.includes("/blogs/") && router.pathname.includes("/webinars/")) { // your code... }
```

The difference is just `&&` or `||`